# Binding ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>> to WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've got a problem with binding an `ObservableCollection` of `ObservableCollections<T>` (`ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>>`):

In my application I have a `TabControl` with `TabItems` which contain all my `ObservableCollection<T>` in `ListBox`(one `ListBox` per Binding `ObservableCollection<T>`), it works fine.
But I would like a "super" `TabItem` in which I have a "super" `ListBox` which contains my "super" `ObservableCollection` (`ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>>`). I would like that this `ListBox` contains all objects `T` and not the `SelectedItem` of each `ObservableCollection<T>`. Of course, if there is a modification in my `ObservableCollection<T>`, this modification is effective in the "super" `ListBox` (that's the goal).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just found a solution !

But if you have solutions, I think it could be help some people ^^